# ASP.NET MVC SiteMap and/or Security Trimming

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

Is there an equivalent in ASP.NET MVC to the SiteMap and Security Trimming Features found in Web Forms?

I am just beginning to learn MVC and was looking for a solution to this to prevent going down the wrong path while learning.

Comment: I am not really looking for third-party/add-on type solutions to this(although it may ultimately be necessary). I am wondering if there is a preferred, out of the box solution to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [ASP.NET MVC SiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider)

Comment: I had come across this in my searches. I was really wondering if there was a preferred, built-in method or procedure to accomplish these requirements

Comment: No, that's why I created the above project.

Comment: Thanks.  For @stephen776, this is a really great project and have used it for a production system already.

Comment: I have to agree with @jfar this is a great project and there's nothing else that comes close.