# ASP.NET MVC Menu Selected Item

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

OK new to MVC. I had asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647135/asp-net-mvc-sitemap-and-or-security-trimming) question earlier and got an answer but I am wondering if there is a simpler solution.

Say I have a master page with a menu laid out as an unordered list. How would I go about setting a css class on the currently selected menu item?

EDIT:

I am using the menu just as it comes setup out of the box when you start a new mvc app

```
<ul id="menu">              
   <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
   <li><%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How are you generating the menu?

Comment: Confused by the downvote...its a basic question of course, by self proclaimed MVC beginner. Just looking for a little guidance on the subject.

Comment: You may have gotten a downvote because you didn't supply code initially.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: im not really worried. I just like my reputation to increase lol

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The answer from Jakub Konecki led me in the right direction... here is the controller action I ended up with:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult MainMenu()
    {
        var items = new List<MenuItem>
        {
            new MenuItem{ Text = "Home", Action = "Index", Controller = "Home", Selected=false },
            new MenuItem{ Text = "My Profile", Action = "Index", Controller = "Profile", Selected = false},
            new MenuItem{ Text = "About", Action = "About", Controller = "Home", Selected = false }
        };

        string action = ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        string controller = ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.Controller == controller && item.Action == action)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
            }
        }

        return PartialView(items);
    }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: +1 - thanks stephen. was looking at this myself just yesterday and this was very useful. btw, did you end up using html.renderpartial or renderaction for this?? also, are you siting the partialview in your masterpage??

Comment: Not in front of my machine right now but I'm pretty sure I went with renderaction in the masterpage

Answer (score 18):

You should pass all relevant information in the Model. Ideally your menu will be rendered as a Partial View by a separate controller method. I have a Navigation controller with actions like MainMenu, FooterMenu, Breadcrumbs, etc that render individual parts.

Your model will be a collection of menu items like:

```
    public class MenuItemModel
    {
        public MenuItemModel()
        {
            SubMenu = new List<MenuItemModel>();
        }

        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Controller { get; set; }            
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }

        public List<MenuItemModel> SubMenu { get; private set; }
    }
```

Your Controller will create a collection of menu items and pass them to the view with the appropriate item selected. Then the view can be as simple as:

```
<ul id="menu">     
    <% foreach(var menuItem in Model.MenuItems) { %> 
        <li><%: Html.ActionLink(menuItem.Text, menuItem.Action, menuItem.Controller, null, new { @class = menuItem.Selected ? "selected" : "" })%></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: But how would I add the 'selected' class to the link that references the current page...seems as if your solution would always apply the class to the first item in the list...

Comment: I have this working for the most part. I was wondering if you would happen to have an example of the controller for this. My menu is working I am just not clear on how to set the selected item in the controller...

Comment: Excellent answer. One improvement for the ActionLink htmlAttributes parameter: `menuItem.Selected ? new { @class = "selected" } : null`

Comment: In the _Layout.cshtml you need to use something like @Html.Action("MainMenu", "Navigation")

Answer (score 4):

stephen,

here's my contribution to the party. a recursive inline function to populate the `<ul><li>` for as many depths as is required (here's the entire ascx file):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<GBC_Art.Controllers.MenuItemModel>>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="GBC_Art.Controllers" %>
<%
    Action<List<MenuItemModel>, int> printNodesRecursively = null;
    printNodesRecursively = (List<MenuItemModel> nodeList, int depth) =>
    {
        if (nodeList == null || nodeList.Count == 0) return;
%>
    <ul<%= depth == 0 ? " id='menu'" : ""%>>  
<%
    foreach (var menuItem in nodeList)
    {
    %>
    <li><%= Html.ActionLink(menuItem.Text, menuItem.Action, menuItem.Controller, null, new { @class = menuItem.Selected ? "selected" : "" })%>
        <%printNodesRecursively(menuItem.SubMenu, depth + 1);%>
    </li>
    <%
        }
%>
    </ul>
<%
    };
    List<MenuItemModel> nodes = Model; 
    printNodesRecursively(nodes, 0);
%>
```

usage -> called as a partialview via the controller as per your example above.

cheers

Comment: awesome...this was going to be next on my list. Thanks for the contribution

Comment: this should probably be a wiki or something since this will be a common issue for those new to MVC such as myself

Comment: you might be correct re the wiki thought. if it does move, remeber to uptick the answer as they don't count in the wiki :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is another possibility, more simple in my opinion using an HTML Helper:

**CSS Class**

```
ul#menu li.selected a {
  background-color: #034af3;
  color: #e8eef4;
}
```

**HTML Helper**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyWebApp.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
{
  public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
  {
    public static string ActivePage(this HtmlHelper helper, string controller, string action)
    {
      string classValue = "";

      string currentController = helper.ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue.ToString();
      string currentAction = helper.ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString();

      if (currentController == controller && currentAction == action)
      {
        classValue = "selected";
      }

      return classValue;
    }
  }
}
```

**Menu on the Layout** :

```
<nav>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="@Html.ActivePage("Home", "Index")">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li class="@Html.ActivePage("Home", "About")">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

More informations here : http://bubblogging.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/mvc-add-selected-class-to-menu/

Answer (score 2):

Just learning MVC now, but I came across this problem and I've figured out a much quicker method of achieving this. It relies on consistent URLs, and isn't affected by query strings.

```
<ul id="menu">              
  <li @(Request.Path.Equals("/") ? Html.Raw("class=\"selected\"") : Html.Raw(""))>
    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
  <li @(Request.Path.Equals("/about") ? Html.Raw("class=\"selected\"") : Html.Raw(""))>
    @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
</ul>
```

Of course, you could handle multiple URLs showing the same item selected through `OR` logic or making a list. But if you're making a list, you'd of course want that in your model. You could have an option highlight for a whole directory by just checking that the start of the string matches.

As is, this would be most suitable to a more static website. If you include this on a LayoutPage, maintenance is pretty easy as you don't have extra classes or functions to maintain. Obviously this wouldn't cut it if you were working off a CMS.

Answer (score 2):

Beside all other solutions you can use this approach to load menus dynamically from Database and make the selected menu active and keep the status across the website.

in the Layout page:

```
<body>
<header>
   @{Html.RenderPartial("_MenuPartial"); }
</header>
@RenderBody()
</body>
```

Then your partial view contains :

```
<nav class="navMain">
<ul>
   foreach (var menu in menuList)
   {
    <li id="@menu.Id"><a href="@menu.Url">@menu.Name</a></li>
   }
</ul>
</nav>
```

To activated the clicked menu, you need a script in the partial view. Also 'active' class in nothing but changing the background color in the CSS.

```
<script>
var selector = '.navMain li';
$(selector).on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    var menuId = $(this).prop("id");
    localStorage.setItem('SelectedMenu', menuId);
});
```

Since we set the HREF for each menu link, we'll lose the active class per post-back. So you need to read the selected menu from localStorage and apply it on the proper menu in partial view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var activeMenuLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('SelectedMenu');
    if (!isNaN(activeMenuLocalStorage)) {
    {
     $("#" + activeMenuLocalStorage).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

More simplest way when `you don't want to change your code much` .. Thanks @Hugo Hilário for the concept

```
using Microsoft.Web.Mvc;     
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace Demo.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class UIHelper
    {             
        public static MvcHtmlString ActivePage(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, string action, string controller)
        { 
            string currentController = helper.ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue.ToString();
            string currentAction = helper.ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString();    

            var actionLink = helper.ActionLink(linkText, action,controller);
            var isCurrentRoute = currentController == controller;// && currentAction == action; uncomment if you want to segregate by action also

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<li{0}>", isCurrentRoute ? " class=\"YourActiveCssClass\"" : string.Empty) + actionLink + "</li>");    

        }
    }
}
```

Layout page

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
          @Html.ActivePage("User", "Index", "User") 
          @Html.ActivePage("State", "Index", "State") 
          @Html.ActivePage("City", "Index", "City") 
     </ul>                     
</div>
```