# Highlight menu and submenu in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, menu, highlight

I am trying to create a menu that highlights the current page. I have found a few answers here, but the problem is I can't see that anyone handles submenus.

There is an answer here that looks enticingly simple: [active menu item - asp.net mvc3 master page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728777/active-menu-item-asp-net-mvc3-master-page)

But as far as I can tell, that one will highlight only the sub menu item if you click on a submenu. I want the submenu item to be highlighted, as well as its parent in the top menu.

E.g. if someone clicks Services, and then Consulting, I would want both of these to be highlighted - Services in the top menu, and Consulting in the submenu. How can I do this?

BTW, I would like to be able to render the submenu both as a dropdown using CSS, and also as a sidebar. How can I take the submenu ul and render it as a sidebar?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple thing, you can modify it according to your needs but basics are here. 
http://developerstyle.posterous.com/highlighting-current-page-in-mvc-3-slick-tric

This above link might be down soon as posterous is closing, here is an update link
http://bhavinsurela.com/highlighting-current-page-in-mvc-3-slick-tric/

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution which I in part also found here in SO and modified, but still as to be improved in order to handle any number of submenus... right now it works for a submenu.

```
namespace PhotoBuss.Web.Back.Controllers
{
public class NavigationController : BaseAdministrationController
{
    //
    // GET: /Common/

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult HeaderMenu()
    {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653226/asp-net-mvc-menu-selected-item

        var items = new List<MenuItemViewModel>
       {
           new MenuItemViewModel{ Text = "home", Action="Index", Controller="Administration", Selected=false},
           new MenuItemViewModel{Text = "manage", Action="Index", Controller="Manage", Selected=false,
           SubMenu = 
           new List<MenuItemViewModel>
           { 
               new MenuItemViewModel{ Text= "photos", Action="Index", Controller="Photos", Selected = false },
               new MenuItemViewModel { Text = "collections", Action="Index", Controller="Collections", Selected=false},
               new MenuItemViewModel { Text = "keywords", Action="Index", Controller="Keywords", Selected=false},
               new MenuItemViewModel { Text = "users", Action="Index", Controller="Users", Selected=false},
               new MenuItemViewModel { Text = "user groups", Action="Index", Controller="Roles", Selected=false}
           }
           },
           new MenuItemViewModel{Text="cms", Action="Index", Controller="CMS", Selected=false}
       };
        string action = ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        string controller = ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.Controller == controller && item.Action == action)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
            }
            foreach(var subItem in item.SubMenu)
                if (subItem.Controller == controller && subItem.Action == action)
                {
                    item.Selected =
                    subItem.Selected = true;
                }
        }

        return PartialView(items);
    }
}
```

The ViewModel

```
public class MenuItemViewModel
{
    public MenuItemViewModel()
    {
        SubMenu = new List<MenuItemViewModel>();
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public List<MenuItemViewModel> SubMenu { get; set; }
}
}
```

The View

```
    @model List<PhotoBuss.Web.Back.Models.Navigation.MenuItemViewModel>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Areas/Admin/Content/CSS/menu.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <div class="headerMenu">
        <ul>
            @foreach (var menuItem in Model)
            {
                <li>@Html.ActionLink(menuItem.Text, menuItem.Action, menuItem.Controller, null,
        new { @class = menuItem.Selected ? "selected" : "" })
                    @if (menuItem.SubMenu.Count >0)
                    {
                        <ul class="@(menuItem.Selected ? "selected" : "")">

                            @foreach (var subMenu in menuItem.SubMenu)
                            {
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink(subMenu.Text, subMenu.Action, subMenu.Controller, null,
        new { @class = subMenu.Selected ? "selected" : "" })</li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    }
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The CSS I'm using with this at the moment:

```
    .headerMenu *
    {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .headerMenu
    {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #78C8FA;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .headerMenu ul
    {
        display: block;
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 3em;
        height: 3em;
    }

    .headerMenu ul li
    {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    .headerMenu ul li a
    {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        padding-left:2em;
        padding-right:2em;
    }

    .headerMenu ul li a:visited
    {
        color: white;
    }

    .headerMenu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li
    {
        color: #333333;
    }
    .selected
    {
        color: #333333 !important;
        display:block !important;
        background-color: #999999;
    }

    .headerMenu ul ul
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        right: 50%;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #999999;
    }

    .headerMenu li:hover > ul, .selected 
    {
        display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple to determine which menu element to highlight by simply using the `ViewContext.RouteData.Values` dictionary, specifically the `Action` and `Controller` keys.

Here's a quick helper method :

```
public static string IsSelected(this RouteValueDictionary dictionary, string controller, string action)
{
    string cssClass = "selected";
    string routeValueController = dictionary["Controller"] as string;
    string routeValueAction = dictionary["Action"] as string;

    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(action) ? 
        routeValueController == controller ? cssClass : string.Empty : 
        routeValueController == controller && routeValueAction == action ? cssClass : string.Empty;
}
```

And can be used from the view as such :

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="@this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values.IsSelected("Default", "Index")">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Default")">Accueil</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It's hard to get into a more specific solution as I'm not familiar with your application structure, but this should give you an idea to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example where they handle the submenus and highlight it.

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#sample4

It uses superfish-navbar.css where you can see how it is done.
It is a very good plugin for menus.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how this helps me, I have no problem rendering submenus with css, I just don't know how to get the class selected on to both the main menu and the submenu according to the method described by Darin Dimitrov linked to above...